# How to retrieve the name of the index from a returned row in python dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to return the name of the country with the maximum number of gold medals in the 'Gold' column.

```
# Summer    Gold    Silver  Bronze  Total   # Winter    Gold.1  Silver.1    Bronze.1    Total.1 # Games Gold.2  Silver.2    Bronze.2    Combined total  ID
Afghanistan 13  0   0   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   13  0   0   2   2   AFG
Algeria 12  5   2   8   15  3   0   0   0   0   15  5   2   8   15  ALG
Argentina   23  18  24  28  70  18  0   0   0   0   41  18  24  28  70  ARG
Armenia 5   1   2   9   12  6   0   0   0   0   11  1   2   9   12  ARM
Australasia 2   3   4   5   12  0   0   0   0   0   2   3   4   5   12  ANZ
```

The following code returns the row object and I want to extract the name of the country which is the index of that row.

```
def return_max_name():

    return df.loc[df['Gold'].idxmax()]

return_max_name()
```

Here is what is returned:

```
# Summer            26
Gold               976
Silver             757
Bronze             666
Total             2399
# Winter            22
Gold.1              96
Silver.1           102
Bronze.1            84
Total.1            282
# Games             48
Gold.2            1072
Silver.2           859
Bronze.2           750
Combined total    2681
ID                 USA
Name: United States, dtype: object
```

I want the function to return 'United States'. I am new to Pandas and I am kinda stuck here so any kind of help will be great!

Comment: kindly share ur input data

Comment: Okay. I have added the input data

Comment: set the country column as index and run this code : ```df.Gold.idxmax()```. it should give u ```Argentina``` based on ur shared data

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just a further observation regarding your solution: What if there was a '.' in the column name like 'Gold.1'? How would I edit the line of your code then?

Comment: then u have to use bracket indexing ... ```df['Gold.1']```

Answer (score 1):

If you found the right row, and the `# Summer` column has the country name, you can get that name by adding the column param to `loc`.

Try changing your return line to this.

```
return df.loc[df.Gold.idxmax(), '# Summer']
```

Comment: The country is already the index of the datagram. I didn't know how to post the dataframe here that's why the data has the indentation problem

Comment: sammywemmy's solution and this one should do the same thing. If the country was not the index, this would allow you to avoid changing the index.